# Spring boot does not generate the json and shows me the white page

Tags: java, spring-boot, sql-server-2017

I've done a simple list with sql server, but it doesn't show me the result, it just shows me the white page.
I have no error in the console. Will the sql server 2017 be? please any help?

**connection to sql server 2017**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=DB_PRUEBA_V1;integratedSecurity=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8090
```

**package app**

```
package app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProyectoV2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProyectoV2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**package model**

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_USERS")
public class Users implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "COD_USER")
    private int codUser;
    @Column(name = "NOM_USER")
    private String nomUser;
    @Column(name = "EMA_USER")
    private String emUser;

    public int getCodUser() {
        return codUser;
    }
    public void setCodUser(int codUser) {
        this.codUser = codUser;
    }
    public String getNomUser() {
        return nomUser;
    }
    public void setNomUser(String nomUser) {
        this.nomUser = nomUser;
    }
    public String getEmUser() {
        return emUser;
    }
    public void setEmUser(String emUser) {
        this.emUser = emUser;
    }

}
```

**package repository**

```
package repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import model.Users;

@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>{

}
```

**service**

```
package service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import model.Users;
import repository.UserDAO;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO dao;

    public List<Users> lista(){
        return dao.findAll();
    }
}
```

**package controller**

```
package controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import model.Users;
import service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/CrudUsers")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService us;

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(path = "/lista", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Users> lista(){
        return us.lista();
    }
}
```

[Whitelabel Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw2Es.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you created each class in different package like below,

```
app --> ProyectoV2Application

model --> Users

repository --> UserDAO

service --> UserService

controller --> UserController
```

But spring boot scans the classes that are either in root package or in sub package of root package, so move all these classes into sub packages of root package

```
app --> ProyectoV2Application

app.model --> Users

app.repository --> UserDAO

app.service --> UserService

app.controller --> UserController
```

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate that a lot.